# Resampling audio with FFMPEG LibAV

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, libav

Well, since FFMPEG documentation and code examples are absolute garbage, I guess my only choise is to go here and aks.

So what I'm trying to do is simply record audio from microphione and write it to the file. So I initialize my input and out formats, I get an audio packet decode it, resample, encode and write. But everytime I try to play and audio there's only a stub of data. It seems like for some reason it writes only a start packet. Which is still very strange and let me explain why:

```
if((response = swr_config_frame(resampleContext, audioOutputFrame, frame) < 0)) qDebug() << "can't configure frame!" <<  av_make_error(response);

if((response = swr_convert_frame(resampleContext, audioOutputFrame, frame) < 0)) qDebug() << "can't resample frame!" <<  av_make_error(response);
```

Here's the code I'm using to resample. My `frame` has data but `swr_convert_frame` writes empty data to `audioOutputFrame`

How do I fix that? FFMPEG literally driving me crazy.

Here's the full code of my class

VideoReader.h

```
#ifndef VIDEOREADER_H
#define VIDEOREADER_H

extern "C"
{
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libswscale/swscale.h>
#include <libavdevice/avdevice.h>
#include "libavutil/audio_fifo.h"
#include "libavformat/avio.h"
#include "libswresample/swresample.h"
#include <inttypes.h>
}

#include <QString>
#include <QElapsedTimer>

class VideoReader
{
public:
    VideoReader();

    bool open(const char* filename);
    bool fillFrame();
    bool readFrame(uint8_t *&frameData);
    void close();

    int width, height;

private:
    bool configInput();
    bool configOutput(const char *filename);
    bool configResampler();

    bool encode(AVFrame *frame, AVCodecContext *encoderContext, AVPacket *outputPacket, int streamIndex, QString type);

    int audioStreamIndex = -1;
    int videoStreamIndex = -1;

    int64_t videoStartPts = 0;
    int64_t audioStartPts = 0;

    AVFormatContext* inputFormatContext = nullptr;
    AVFormatContext* outputFormatContext = nullptr;

    AVCodecContext* videoDecoderContext = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* videoEncoderContext = nullptr;

    AVCodecContext* audioDecoderContext = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext* audioEncoderContext = nullptr;

    AVFrame* videoInputFrame = nullptr;
    AVFrame* audioInputFrame = nullptr;

    AVFrame* videoOutputFrame = nullptr;
    AVFrame* audioOutputFrame = nullptr;

    AVPacket* inputPacket = nullptr;

    AVPacket* videoOutputPacket = nullptr;
    AVPacket* audioOutputPacket = nullptr;

    SwsContext* innerScaleContext = nullptr;
    SwsContext* outerScaleContext = nullptr;

    SwrContext *resampleContext = nullptr;
};

#endif // VIDEOREADER_H
```

VideoReader.cpp

```
#include "VideoReader.h"

#include <QDebug>

static const char* av_make_error(int errnum)
{
    static char str[AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE];
    memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));
    return av_make_error_string(str, AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum);
}

VideoReader::VideoReader()
{

}

bool VideoReader::open(const char *filename)
{
    if(!configInput()) return false;
    if(!configOutput(filename)) return false;
    if(!configResampler()) return false;

    return true;
}

bool VideoReader::fillFrame()
{
    auto convertToYUV = [=](AVFrame* frame)
    {
        int response = 0;

        if((response = sws_scale(outerScaleContext, frame->data, frame->linesize, 0, videoEncoderContext->height, videoOutputFrame->data, videoOutputFrame->linesize)) < 0) qDebug() << "can't rescale" << av_make_error(response);
    };

    auto convertAudio = [this](AVFrame* frame)
    {
        int response = 0;

        auto& out = audioOutputFrame;
        qDebug() << out->linesize[0] << out->nb_samples;
        if((response = swr_convert_frame(resampleContext, audioOutputFrame, frame)) < 0) qDebug() << "can't resample frame!" << av_make_error(response);
        qDebug() << "poop";
    };

    auto decodeEncode = [=](AVPacket* inputPacket, AVFrame* inputFrame, AVCodecContext* decoderContext,
                            AVPacket* outputPacket, AVFrame* outputFrame, AVCodecContext* encoderContext,
                            std::function<void (AVFrame*)> convertFunc,
                            int streamIndex, int64_t startPts, QString type)
    {
        int response = avcodec_send_packet(decoderContext, inputPacket);
        if(response < 0) { qDebug() << "failed to send" << type << "packet!" <<  av_make_error(response); return false; }

        response = avcodec_receive_frame(decoderContext, inputFrame);
        if(response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) { av_packet_unref(inputPacket); return false; }
        else if (response < 0) { qDebug() << "failed to decode" << type << "frame!" << response << av_make_error(response); return false; }

        if(encoderContext)
        {
            outputFrame->pts = inputPacket->pts - startPts;

            convertFunc(inputFrame);
            if(!encode(outputFrame, encoderContext, outputPacket, streamIndex, type)) return false;
        }

        av_packet_unref(inputPacket);

        return true;
    };

    while(av_read_frame(inputFormatContext, inputPacket) >= 0) //actually read packet
    {
        if(inputPacket->stream_index == videoStreamIndex)
        {
            if(!videoStartPts) videoStartPts = inputPacket->pts;
            if(decodeEncode(inputPacket, videoInputFrame, videoDecoderContext, videoOutputPacket, videoOutputFrame, videoEncoderContext, convertToYUV, videoStreamIndex, videoStartPts, "video")) break;
        }
        else if(inputPacket->stream_index == audioStreamIndex)
        {
            if(!audioStartPts) audioStartPts = inputPacket->pts;
            if(decodeEncode(inputPacket, audioInputFrame, audioDecoderContext, audioOutputPacket, audioOutputFrame, audioEncoderContext, convertAudio, audioStreamIndex, audioStartPts, "audio")) break;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

bool VideoReader::readFrame(uint8_t *&frameData)
{
    if(!fillFrame()) { qDebug() << "readFrame method failed!"; return false; };

    const int bytesPerPixel = 4;

    uint8_t* destination[bytesPerPixel] = {frameData, NULL, NULL, NULL};
    int destinationLinesize[bytesPerPixel] = { videoInputFrame->width * bytesPerPixel,  0, 0, 0};

    sws_scale(innerScaleContext, videoInputFrame->data, videoInputFrame->linesize, 0, videoInputFrame->height, destination, destinationLinesize);

    return true;
}

void VideoReader::close()
{
    encode(NULL, videoEncoderContext, videoOutputPacket, videoStreamIndex, "video");
    encode(NULL, audioEncoderContext, audioOutputPacket, audioStreamIndex, "audio");

    if(av_write_trailer(outputFormatContext) < 0) { qDebug() << "failed to write trailer"; };

    avformat_close_input(&outputFormatContext);
    avformat_free_context(outputFormatContext);
    avformat_close_input(&inputFormatContext);
    avformat_free_context(inputFormatContext);

    av_frame_free(&videoInputFrame);
    av_frame_free(&audioInputFrame);

    av_frame_free(&videoOutputFrame);
    av_frame_free(&audioOutputFrame);

    av_packet_free(&inputPacket);

    av_packet_free(&videoOutputPacket);
    av_packet_free(&audioOutputPacket);

    avcodec_free_context(&videoDecoderContext);
    avcodec_free_context(&videoEncoderContext);

    avcodec_free_context(&audioDecoderContext);
    avcodec_free_context(&audioEncoderContext);

    sws_freeContext(innerScaleContext);
    sws_freeContext(outerScaleContext);

    swr_free(&resampleContext);
}

bool VideoReader::configInput()
{
    avdevice_register_all();

    inputFormatContext = avformat_alloc_context();

    if(!inputFormatContext) { qDebug() << "can't create context!"; return false; }

    const char* inputFormatName = "dshow";/*"gdigrab"*/
    AVInputFormat* inputFormat = av_find_input_format(inputFormatName);

    if(!inputFormat){ qDebug() << "Can't find" << inputFormatName; return false; }

    AVDictionary* options = NULL;
    av_dict_set(&options, "framerate", "30", 0);
    av_dict_set(&options, "video_size", "1920x1080", 0);

    if(avformat_open_input(&inputFormatContext, "video=HD USB Camera:audio=Microphone (High Definition Audio Device)" /*"desktop"*/, inputFormat, &options) != 0) { qDebug() << "can't open video file!"; return false; }

    AVCodecParameters* videoCodecParams = nullptr;
    AVCodecParameters* audioCodecParams = nullptr;
    AVCodec* videoDecoder = nullptr;
    AVCodec* audioDecoder = nullptr;

    for (uint i = 0; i < inputFormatContext->nb_streams; ++i)
    {
        auto stream = inputFormatContext->streams[i];
        auto codecParams = stream->codecpar;

        if(codecParams->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO) { audioStreamIndex = i; audioDecoder = avcodec_find_decoder(codecParams->codec_id); audioCodecParams = codecParams; }
        if(codecParams->codec_type == AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) { videoStreamIndex = i; videoDecoder = avcodec_find_decoder(codecParams->codec_id); videoCodecParams = codecParams; }

        if(audioStreamIndex != -1 && videoStreamIndex != -1) break;
    }

    if(audioStreamIndex == -1) { qDebug() << "failed to find audio stream inside file"; return false; }
    if(videoStreamIndex == -1) { qDebug() << "failed to find video stream inside file"; return false; }

    auto configureCodecContext = [=](AVCodecContext*& context, AVCodec* decoder, AVCodecParameters* params, AVFrame*& frame, QString type)
    {
        context = avcodec_alloc_context3(decoder);
        if(!context) { qDebug() << "failed to create" << type << "decoder context!"; return false; }

        if(avcodec_parameters_to_context(context, params) < 0) { qDebug() << "can't initialize input" << type << "decoder context"; return false; }

        if(avcodec_open2(context, decoder, NULL) < 0) { qDebug() << "can't open" << type << "decoder"; return false; }

        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if(!frame) { qDebug() << "can't allocate" << type << "frame"; return false; }

        return true;
    };

    if(!configureCodecContext(videoDecoderContext, videoDecoder, videoCodecParams, videoInputFrame, "video")) return false;
    if(!configureCodecContext(audioDecoderContext, audioDecoder, audioCodecParams, audioInputFrame, "audio")) return false;

    audioDecoderContext->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
    audioInputFrame->channel_layout = audioDecoderContext->channel_layout;

    inputPacket = av_packet_alloc();
    if(!inputPacket) { qDebug() << "can't allocate input packet!";  return false; }

    //first frame, needed fo initialization
    if(!fillFrame()) { qDebug() << "Failed to fill frame on init!"; return false; };

    width = videoDecoderContext->width;
    height = videoDecoderContext->height;

    innerScaleContext = sws_getContext(width, height, videoDecoderContext->pix_fmt,
                                       width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_RGB0,
                                       SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL);

    outerScaleContext = sws_getContext(width, height, videoDecoderContext->pix_fmt,
                                       width, height, AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P,
                                       SWS_FAST_BILINEAR,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL,
                                       NULL);


    if(!innerScaleContext) { qDebug() << "failed to initialize scaler context"; return false; }

    return true;
}

bool VideoReader::configOutput(const char *filename)
{
    avformat_alloc_output_context2(&outputFormatContext, NULL, NULL, filename);
    if(!outputFormatContext) { qDebug() << "failed to create output context"; return false; }

    AVOutputFormat* outputFormat = outputFormatContext->oformat;

    auto prepareOutputContext = [=](AVCodecContext*& encoderContext,
                                    std::function<void (AVCodecContext*, AVCodec*)> configureContextFunc,
                                    std::function<void (AVFrame*)> configureFrameFunc,
                                    AVCodecID codecId, AVFrame*& frame, AVPacket*& packet, QString type)
    {
        auto stream = avformat_new_stream(outputFormatContext, NULL);
        if(!stream) { qDebug() << "failed to allocate output" << type << "stream"; return false; }

        AVCodec* encoder = avcodec_find_encoder(codecId);
        if(!encoder) { qDebug() << "failed to find" << type << "encoder!"; return false; }

        encoderContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(encoder);
        if(!encoderContext) { qDebug() << "failed to create video encoder context!"; return false; }

        configureContextFunc(encoderContext, encoder);

        int result = avcodec_open2(encoderContext, encoder, NULL);
        if(result < 0) { qDebug() << "failed to open audio encoder" << av_make_error(result); return false; }
        if(avcodec_parameters_from_context(stream->codecpar, encoderContext) < 0) { qDebug() << "failed to copy parameters to audio output stream"; return false; }

        packet = av_packet_alloc();
        if(!packet) {qDebug() << "failed allocate output" << type << "packet"; return false;}

        frame = av_frame_alloc();
        if(!frame) { qDebug() << "can't allocate output" << type << "frame"; return false; }

        configureFrameFunc(frame);

        av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);

        return true;
    };

    auto configureAudioFrame = [=](AVFrame* frame)
    {
        frame->nb_samples = audioEncoderContext->frame_size;
        frame->format = audioEncoderContext->sample_fmt;
        frame->sample_rate = audioEncoderContext->sample_rate;
        frame->channel_layout = av_get_default_channel_layout(audioDecoderContext->channels);
    };

    auto configureAudioEncoderContext = [=](AVCodecContext* encoderContext, AVCodec* encoder)
    {
        encoderContext->bit_rate = 64000;
        encoderContext->sample_fmt = encoder->sample_fmts[0];
        encoderContext->sample_rate = 44100;
        encoderContext->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO;
        encoderContext->channel_layout = AV_CH_LAYOUT_STEREO;
        encoderContext->channels = av_get_channel_layout_nb_channels(encoderContext->channel_layout);
    };

    auto configureVideoFrame = [=](AVFrame* frame)
    {
        frame->format = videoEncoderContext->pix_fmt;
        frame->width  = videoEncoderContext->width;
        frame->height = videoEncoderContext->height;
    };

    auto configureVideoEncoderContext = [=](AVCodecContext* encoderContext, AVCodec* encoder)
    {
        encoderContext->width = videoDecoderContext->width;
        encoderContext->height = videoDecoderContext->height;
        encoderContext->pix_fmt = encoder->pix_fmts[0];
        encoderContext->gop_size = 10;
        encoderContext->max_b_frames = 1;
        encoderContext->framerate = AVRational{30, 1};
        encoderContext->time_base = AVRational{1, 30};

        av_opt_set(encoderContext->priv_data, "preset", "ultrafast", 0);
        av_opt_set(encoderContext->priv_data, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
    };

    if(!prepareOutputContext(videoEncoderContext, configureVideoEncoderContext, configureVideoFrame, outputFormat->video_codec, videoOutputFrame, videoOutputPacket, "video")) return false;
    if(!prepareOutputContext(audioEncoderContext, configureAudioEncoderContext, configureAudioFrame, outputFormat->audio_codec, audioOutputFrame, audioOutputPacket, "audio")) return false;

    if(outputFormat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER) outputFormat->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    int result = 0;
    if(!(outputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE))
        if((result = avio_open(&outputFormatContext->pb, filename, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE)) < 0)
            { qDebug() << "failed to open file" <<  av_make_error(result); return false; }

    result = avformat_write_header(outputFormatContext, NULL);
    if(result < 0) {qDebug() << "failed to write header!" << av_make_error(result); return false; }

    return true;
}

bool VideoReader::configResampler()
{

    resampleContext = swr_alloc_set_opts(NULL,
                                         av_get_default_channel_layout(audioEncoderContext->channels),
                                         audioEncoderContext->sample_fmt,
                                         audioEncoderContext->sample_rate,
                                         av_get_default_channel_layout(audioDecoderContext->channels),
                                         audioDecoderContext->sample_fmt,
                                         audioDecoderContext->sample_rate,
                                         0, NULL);
    if (!resampleContext) { qDebug() << "Could not allocate resample context"; return false; }

    int error;
    if ((error = swr_init(resampleContext)) < 0) { qDebug() << "Could not open resample context"; swr_free(&resampleContext); return false; }

    return true;
}

bool VideoReader::encode(AVFrame* frame, AVCodecContext* encoderContext, AVPacket* outputPacket, int streamIndex, QString type)
{
    int response;

    response = avcodec_send_frame(encoderContext, frame);
    if(response < 0) { qDebug() << "failed to send" << type << "frame" << av_make_error(response); return false; }

    while(response >= 0)
    {
        response = avcodec_receive_packet(encoderContext, outputPacket);
        if(response == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || response == AVERROR_EOF) { av_packet_unref(outputPacket); continue; }
        else if (response < 0) { qDebug() << "failed to encode" << type << "frame!" << response << av_make_error(response); return false; }

        outputPacket->stream_index = streamIndex;

        AVStream *inStream = inputFormatContext->streams[streamIndex];
        AVStream *outStream = outputFormatContext->streams[streamIndex];

        av_packet_rescale_ts(outputPacket, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base);

        if((response = av_interleaved_write_frame(outputFormatContext, outputPacket)) != 0) { qDebug() << "Failed to write" << type << "packet!" <<  av_make_error(response); av_packet_unref(outputPacket); return false; }

        av_packet_unref(outputPacket);
    }

    return true;
}
```

I could try to write down shorter example if needed

Comment: Presumably you've tried the [example](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/2.1/doc_2examples_2resampling_audio_8c-example.html) that comes with the `ffmpeg` source?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. That was a method I initially tried to solve my problem

Comment: Aaaand that example just doesn't work. It creates a file, buit file is unplayable

Comment: The example works okay for me.  If it doesn't work for you that suggests the problem might not be with the resampling itself but elsewhere.

Comment: So how can I find it out? That example doesn't give me any error message, it only says "Resampling succeeded. Play the output file with the command.." in the end. But when I try - it's unplayable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, here are several circumstances that `swr_convert_frame` might write nothing:

1. You did not initialize your output frame correctly. If so, checkout the following snippet:

```
  audioFrame = av_frame_alloc();
  if (audioFrame == NULL) {
    // error handling
  }
  audioFrame->format = /* the sample format you'd like to use */; 
  audioFrame->channel_layout = audioCodecContext->channel_layout;
  audioFrame->nb_samples = audioCodecContext->frame_size;
  if (av_frame_get_buffer(encoder->audioFrame, 0) < 0) {
    // error handling
  }
```

2. The samples in your input frame is not enough for producing a complete output frame. If so, you need `swr_get_delay`.

```
if (swr_convert(swrContext, audioFrame->data,
                audioFrame->nb_samples,
                (uint8_t const**)frame->data, frame->nb_samples) < 0) {
  // handle error
}
// do stuff with your audioFrame
...

while (swr_get_delay(swrContext, audioCodecContext->sample_rate)
       > audioFrame->nb_samples) {
  if (swr_convert(swrContext, audioFrame->data,
                  audioFrame->nb_samples, NULL, 0) < 0) {
    // handle error
  }
  // do stuff with your audioFrame
}
```

Anyway, more informations, at least a minimal reproducible sample should be provided for further diagnose.

I have to agree that documentation of `libav` is too poor, it used to drive me crazy too. But cursing authors of `libav` won't do any help, and what's more, Open Source contributors do not owe you anything.

Comment: My audio frame seems to be configured correctly it has all the needed fields filled and it also has memory allocated for it's buffer. Tried to use swr_get_delay for changing nb_samples field but just got a new error. I updated my question and added whole class code

Comment: I'm absolutely agree that cursing won't do any good, but just a thought: if somebody make a project that huge and that widely used, shouldn't that person be at least a little concerned about making it possible to work with? I defenitely going to make a tutorial about FFMPEG once I finish with that problem. Just to make world a less sufferable place to be

Comment: can you please explain how do I use `swr_get_delay` for that context?

Comment: I posted piece of my code above, hope it helps. The principle behind the function is: `swr_convert` does not perform a frame-to-frame conversion since output frame may require less or more samples than input frame provides, some frames may left in buffer of `SwrContext`. It's up to you to flush them out when appropriate.

Comment: Yes, that solved the issue. Thanks you so much for your help